# NSURLConnection swizzling in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlconnection, swizzling

I have created NSURLConnection method swizzling for sendSynchronousRequest, however its not been working below is my code. Whenever I am trying to call this from main function, its crashing.

```
    let originalRequestSyncSelector = #selector(self.sendSynchronousRequest(_:returning:))
    let swizzledRequestSyncSelector = #selector(self.swizzSendSynchronousRequest(_:returning:error:))

    let originalSyncRequestMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, originalRequestSyncSelector)
    let swizzledSyncRequestMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledRequestSyncSelector)

    if originalSyncRequestMethod == nil || swizzledSyncRequestMethod == nil {
      return
    }
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalSyncRequestMethod!, swizzledSyncRequestMethod!)


  @objc func swizzSendSynchronousRequest(_ request: NSURLRequest?, returning response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Data? {

    var tempData: Data?
    print("Inside Sync Swizzled Method")
    print("------------\(String(describing: request))")
    return tempData
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of things that might cause problems:

1. The method signatures are different. The original implementation does not have an `error` parameter, but is a throwing function. Also, unlike your swizzled method, `sendSynchronousRequest` takes a `URLRequest` instead of an `NSURLRequest`.
2. You're swizzling an instance and a class method. I'm not sure how (or if) this can be made to work.
3. `sendSynchronousRequest` is exposed to Swift as a throwing function. It works if your swizzled function is not marked with `throws`, but throwing functions can't be exposed to ObjC and might cause issues when being swizzled.

Here is some working code for a playground:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectiveC

extension NSURLConnection {
    @objc static func swizzSendSynchronousRequest(_ request: URLRequest?, returning response: URLResponse?) -> Data? {

        print("Inside Sync Swizzled Method")
        print("------------\(String(describing: request))")
        return Data()
    }
}

let originalRequestSyncSelector = #selector(NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(_:returning:))
let swizzledRequestSyncSelector = #selector(NSURLConnection.swizzSendSynchronousRequest(_:returning:))

let originalSyncRequestMethod = class_getClassMethod(NSURLConnection.self, originalRequestSyncSelector)
let swizzledSyncRequestMethod = class_getClassMethod(NSURLConnection.self, swizzledRequestSyncSelector)

method_exchangeImplementations(originalSyncRequestMethod!, swizzledSyncRequestMethod!)


let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://example.com")!)
do {
    let data = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returning: nil)
    print(data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Regardless, I think it would be a better idea to perform swizzling in Objective-C.
There's [much better documentation](https://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) on how to do that, and you can avoid pitfalls in Swift <-> Objective-C bridging magic.